# How to Order Posts by Taxonomy in Jetengine Plugin

Tags: plugins

I'm creating a classifieds website, this is my first project with Jetengine.

On this classifieds site I created a Post Type called Classifieds and then a Taxonomy called "Highlights" where I have two options:

Featured Ad (featured-ad)
Simple Ad (simple-ad)

In the Linting Grid I wanted to list the posts in order of the Taxonomy and the posts marked as "advertised-highlighted" would have to appear first.

How do I include Featured Ads and Simple Ads in the same Listing Grid?

Is there any way for this? Do I have to do it via code?

Thanks for your attention.